# Handle $_GET safely PHP

Tags: php, security, get

I have a code like this:

```
$myvar=$_GET['var'];

// a bunch of code without any connection to DB where $myvar is used like this:

$local_directory=dirname(__FILE__).'/images/'.$myvar;
if ($myvar && $handle = opendir($local_directory)) {
    $i=0; 
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if(strstr($entry, 'sample_'.$language.'-'.$type)) {
            $result[$i]=$entry;
            $i++;
        }
    } 
    closedir($handle);
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

I'm a little confused with a number of stripping and escaping functions, so the question  is,  what do i need to do with `$myvar` for this code to be safe? In my case i don't make any database connections.

Comment: Does the `.$myvar` directory exist already, or do you create it on the fly?

Comment: @Pekka: That code doesn't create anything on the fly.

Comment: Does sanitize all inputs with php filters, it should be more than enough for your code. http://br.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: @Niklas according to the OP, the code above is just an excerpt.

Comment: Smartass answer: nothing, since you're using a [single quoted string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), so the directory you're trying to access is literally `images/.$myvar`, dollar sign and all.

Comment: @llmari Karonen. fooled us all :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to prevent directory traversal attacks, so you don't want the person putting in `./../../../` or something, hoping to read out files or filenames, depending on what you are doing.

I often using something like this:

```
$myvar =  preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/","",$_GET['var']);
```

This replaces anything that isn't `a-zA-Z0-9-` with a blank, so if the variable contains say, `*`, this code would delete that.

I then change the a-zA-Z0-9- to match which characters I want to be allowed in the string. I can then lock it down to only containing numbers or whatever I need.

Comment: works well in most cases. attention shall be payed when you have data you want to protect in a sibling folder. That's why I tend to prefer to explicitly state what's allowed, rather than trying to block out what I'd avoid.

Comment: Yes, of course. In cases where it's very clear, you could change the regex to something like "/^(option1|option2|option3)"/ instead. Always restrict input as much as possible.

Comment: All good suggestions indeed. I tend to rely on arrays (or other stuff in more complex situations) because of the flexibility of keeping in sync w/ FS and avoiding duplicated code/logic. But hey, good points anyways.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on the context - using a regex like this is a nice quick simple solution that can be thrown in without much thought, though yeah, often you'll want to compare to known values from the DB. Really depends on exactly what you are doing. Plus regex's make me feel like a coding guru. :)

Comment: ah ah ah. definitely good points. And I know how it feels. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's really, really dangerous to do something like: `opendir($local_directory)` where `$local_directory` is a value which could come from the outside.

What if someone passes in something like `../../../../../../../../../etc` ...or something like that? You risk of compromising security of your host.

You can take a glance here, to start: 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

IMHO, if you don't create anything on the fly, you should have something like:

```
$allowed_dirs = array('dir1','dir2', 'dir3');
if (!in_array($myvar, $allowed_dirs)) {
    // throw an error and log what has happened
}
```

You can do this right after you receive your input from "outside". If it's impractical for you to do this because the number of image dirs can vary with time and you're afraid of missing the sync with your codebase, you could also populate the array of valid values making a scan of subdirectories you have into the image folders first.

So, at the end, you could have something like:

```
$allowed_dirs = array();
if ($handle = opendir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            $allowed_dirs[] = $entry;
    } 
    closedir($handle);
}
$myvar=$_GET['var'];

// you can deny access to dirs you want to protect like this
unset($allowed_dirs['private_stuff']);

// rest of code
$local_directory = dirname(__FILE__) . "/images/.$myvar";
if (in_array(".$myvar", $allowed_dirs) && $handle = opendir($local_directory)) {
    $i=0; 
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if(strstr($entry, 'sample_'.$language.'-'.$type)) {
            $result[$i]=$entry;
            $i++;
        }
    } 
    closedir($handle);
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Code above is NOT optimized. But let's avoid premature optimization in this case (stating this to avoid another "nice" downvote); snippet is just to get you the idea of explicitly allowing values VS alternate approach of allowing everything unless matching a certain pattern. I think the former is more secure.

Comment: Any example how to filter it?

Comment: The nice thing about syntax highlighting is that certain mistakes are immediately visible.

Comment: I look for valid subfolders I want to dinamically handle. Then I allow outside parameter to be specified among these folders only. I do not allow anything else to be passed in.

Comment: Because you seem to allow any subdirectory of `images` as valid input, you could just as well not use a directory whitelist at all and just use a much simpler regex-based solution. Remember that `opendir` already fails if a directory doesn't exist.

Comment: You're right, Niklas B. I didn't want to be comprehensive in the code above. But the array solution easily allow you to unset directories you don't want to allow user access to (either while scanning source dir or later), and yet accomodate dynamic values. BTW you seem pretty harsh w/ me today. I must have done something to you. I apologize, not my intention! ;-)

Comment: PS @Niklas The point is that a directory might exist. But you might not want user to access it. There's a difference between having a directory on the FS and wanting the user to access it. That's how I see it. I might be wrong.

Comment: @maraspin: Sorry, that's nothing personal ;) I just think this solution is overly complex. You can also exclude certain values using regex, that's not the problem.

Comment: @niklas just kidding ;-) My intention was to show the other approach to filtering: allow nothing but what has been explicitly done so. arrays give you flexibility, because you can populate them with all subfolders, and easily specify/remove from the array only the ones you want not to allow access to. As a new dir is created, not problem to allow access to it. W/ a regex might not always be so easy to do. And IMHO it's much easier to screw up w/ RegEx rather than arrays. ;-) You know, I have some issues w/ syntax sometimes (pun w/ above intended) :-D

Answer (score 2):

Let me just note for completeness that, *if* you can be sure your code will only be run on Unixish systems (such as Linux), the *only* things you need to ensure are that:

1. `$myvar` does not contain any slash (`"/"`, U+002F) or null (`"\0"`, U+0000) characters, and that
2. `$myvar` is not empty or equal to `"."` (or, equivalently, that `".$myvar"` is not equal to `"."` or `".."`).

That's because, on a Unix filesystem, the only directory separator character (and one of the two characters not allowed in filenames, the other being the null character `"\0"`) is the slash, and the only special directory entries pointing upwards in the directory tree are `"."` and `".."`.

However, if your code might someday be run on Windows, then you'll need to disallow more characters (at least the backslash, `"\\"`, and probably others too).  I'm not familiar enough with Windows filesystem conventions to say exactly which characters you'd need to disallow there, but the *safe* approach is to do [as Rich Bradshaw suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9759225) and *only* allow characters that you *know* are safe.

Answer (score 1):

As with every data that comes from an untrusted source: Validate it before use and encode it properly when passing it to another context.

As for the former, you first need to specify what properties the data must have to be considered valid. This primarily depends on the purpose of its use.

In your case, the value of `$myvar` should probably be at least a valid directory name but it could also be a valid relative path composed of directory names, depending on your requirements. At this point, you are supposed to specify these requirements.